# Eloquent Javascript A list returns undefined , Why?

Tags: javascript, object, data-structures

Task

---

A list

Objects, as generic blobs of values, can be used to build all sorts of data structures. A common data structure is the list (not to be confused with the array). A list is a nested set of objects, with the first object holding a reference to the second, the second to the third, and so on.

var list = {
  value: 1,
  rest: {
    value: 2,
    rest: {
      value: 3,
      rest: null
    }
  }
};
The resulting objects form a chain, like this:

A linked list
A nice thing about lists is that they can share parts of their structure. For example, if I create two new values {value: 0, rest: list} and {value: -1, rest: list} (with list referring to the variable defined earlier), they are both independent lists, but they share the structure that makes up their last three elements. In addition, the original list is also still a valid three-element list.

Write a function arrayToList that builds up a data structure like the previous one when given [1, 2, 3]

---

The over all goal is to create a function that creates a list structure as mentioned in the Exercise "A list" in the Data Structures Chapter.

```
function arrayToList(array){
  var list = {};
  var i = 0;
  var rest = ((i < array.length) ? (i++,{value: array[i],rest: rest}): null) ;
  list = {
    value: array[0],
    rest: rest
  }
  return list;
}
```

What I was hoping to accomplish was use the rest variable to call itself until the var i was greater than the array length, but when I run the code the rest property return undefined... my question is why does it not behave as recursive call to the same ternary var rest. I am fairly new to javascript so any advise or articles that would help me understand why this happens would be great.

Comment: It would be helpful if the task text was also provided.

Comment: "why does it not behave as recursive call to the same ternary var rest" --- because it's not a function?

Comment: @zerkms Ok so in order for it to call it self it would have to be a function. so the var rest cannot be called inside an object and have it refer to the ternary expression ?

Comment: Terenary is just a conditional statement, expecting it to call itself would be the same as expecting an if block to call itself. You could try a while block with a conditional inside or maybe an actual recursive function.

Comment: Ok makes perfect sense, in this case is implementing a while loop more appropriate than an actual recursive function or is a bit silly to ask? @scrappedcola

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()`

```js
var list = {};
var arr = [1,2,3];
arr.reduce((o, prop, index, array) => {
  o["value"] = prop; 
  o["rest"] = index < array.length -1 ? {} : null;
  return o["rest"]
}, list);

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Not familiar with prototype but will definitely revise that topic for a better understanding.

Comment: @CesarPerez Not certain what you mean?

Comment: it's not prototype you need to be familiar with, it's the reduce function

Comment: Ok will look it up I think the concept has to do with "folding" or "flattening" the array into one value, but will def check it more in depth.

Answer (score 0):

As commenters have said, you aren't actually making this function recursive - it never calls itself.

To achieve what you want you'd have to do this:

```
function arrayToList(array){
  var list = {};
  var rest = ((array.length) ? (arrayToList(array.slice(1))) : null) ;
  list = {
    value: array[0],
    rest: rest
  }
  return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern javascript, you can simply do this:

```
var arrayToList = array => array.slice().reverse().reduce((rest, value) => ({ value, rest }), { rest:null });
```

which, after running it through a transpiler, becomes

```
var arrayToList = function arrayToList(array) {
  return array.slice().reverse().reduce(function (rest, value) {
    return { value: value, rest: rest };
  }, { rest:null });
};
```

Comment: Last `rest` value is not set to `null`

Comment: good point! I didn't read the edited question very thoroughly

Comment: Now it is fixed

Comment: Why do you use `.reverse()`?

Comment: OP expects `var list = { value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: null } } };`, no?

Comment: No. Presently values proceed 3 to 1 from outer to inner.

Comment: @guest271314 - you must be doing something wrong then - this code produces identical result to your answer - maybe because in the console it looks different - I'll swap the order of value and rest - yeah, it just looks different because of the order of rest/value - I assure you the object is the same though - changed code so the output should now be identical to your answer

Comment: Ah, `array` is revered at each call. If parameter to `arrayToList` is same array. Try calling twice with same array as parameter.

Comment: nevermind - added a slice :p - your code is cleaner - I just wanted to do it as a single line :p

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];

var arrayToList = function(array) {
  var list = {};
  var array = array.reverse();
  var arrLength = array.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {           
    var newList = function() {              
      if (i) {
        return list;
      } else {
        return null
      }                  
    }                 
     list = {
       value: array[i],
       list: newList()
     }                             
  }
  return list;
}

console.log(arrayToList(array));
```

I also learn javascript from that book and i struggled with this one.
I think this is more close to what we have learned in the book so far.

Using reduce function is also a great way to resolve this , but it is not yet presented in the book and we presume we have no idea how to use it.